# I'm unable to send a response to my react.js using http.get in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get the temperature data from my node.js backend sent to react.js but i kept getting `res.send is not a funtion`

Sample code here

```js
app.get("/gettemperature", (req, res) => {
    const email = req.query.email;

    let stmt = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?`;
    let todo = [email];
    
    db.query(stmt, todo, (err, results, fields) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
      }
      
      if(results.length > 0 ){
          let id = results[0].id;

          let getID = `SELECT * FROM controlModules WHERE deviceowner=?`;
          let getidData = [id];

          db.query(getID, getidData, (err, resulta, fields) => {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err.message);
            }

            if(resulta.length > 0){
              
              let lanip = resulta[0].ipaddress;

              let url = "http://"+lanip+"/data";

              http.get(url,(res) => {
                  let body = "";
          
                  res.on("data", (chunk) => {
                      body += chunk;
                  });
          
                  res.on("end", () => {
                      try {
                        let json = JSON.parse(body);
                        const temp_actual = json.temperature.value;
                        console.log(temp_actual);
                        
                        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                        res.end(
                          JSON.stringify({
                            value: temp_actual
                          })
                        );
                      } catch (error) {
                          console.error(error.message);
                      };
                  });
          
              }).on("error", (error) => {
                  console.error(error.message);
              });
            }
          });
      }

    });

  });
```

i really need to return/send/respond the temperature data to my front end but i'm getting said error, is there a different way to return data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing up an HTTP server you wrote in Node (although you haven't shown any relevant code) and an HTTP client you also wrote in Node.

`res` is an argument received by the callback you pass to `http.get` and contains data about the response received by your HTTP client.

Meanwhile, somewhere else (not shown) you have **a different** variable also called `res` which is the object your HTTP server uses to send its response to the browser running your React code.

You are calling `res.send` and wanting `res` to be the latter but it is really the former.

Since you haven't shown us the HTTP server code, it is hard to say where that `res` is, but there is a good chance you have [shadowed it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) and can solve your problem by using different names (e.g. `client_res` and `server_res`).

---

That said. I strongly recommend avoiding using the `http` module directly as the API follows out of date design patterns and isn't very friendly. Consider using `fetch` or `axios` for making HTTP requests and Express.js for writing HTTP servers.

Comment: i've updated the pasted code above, to show how the process works, i really need to return temperature value to my front end.

Comment: @IanDucao — "Since you haven't shown us the HTTP server code, it is hard to say where that res is, but there is a good chance you have shadowed it and can solve your problem by using different names (e.g. client_res and server_res)." ← Now you've shown the relevant code, I can see that this assumption was correct. Do what I said.

Comment: i'm able to display the exact temperature value using console.log but having issues returning temperature value to the front end which makes it usable.

Comment: You keep restating your problem but I've already given you the fix.